# Cannot replicate chrome request (Copy as curl)

Tags: web-scraping, curl, networking

I am trying to replicate a http get request from chrome via curl or postman or insomnia, ...

When I try to execute the query on any of the above I get a 403 error. I included all headers and cookies. When I redo the request in chrome ( or firefox also tested ) it works as often as I want however. What could the cause of this be how can I replicate the entire request?